# Laravel 4 understanding resources

Tags: php, laravel

So, I'm starting to learn L4, but having a few issues. I'm trying to read the documentation on their website, but it seems to be incomplete, or not well done (maybe i'm too newbie at this point). However.

What I'm trying to figure out is, when I've created a resource, and added a route like this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

how would i create a form, so when i submit something inside "laravel/public/users/create" the method "store" would get triggered? do i need to create a own route for this? would i use the PUT? how should me ACTION URL look like?

Is there any one that can create a good example for me on this one? On how the view / controller would look like?

Answer (score 0):

This page should have everything covered for you: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

The "Actions Handled By Resource Controller" is especially helpful. In your example, you would make a class called UsersController with a postCreate() method which will automatically be called when a post  request is sent to /users/create.

Comment: This seems uncorrect, why would you need a postCreate when using resoucres? Am i getting something wrong here? postCreate seems more lika a restfull controller.

Comment: As far as I know, resources are an extension of controllers and are still RESTful. If you want to do the routing outside of the controller, I guess you'd have to do `Route::post('user/create', 'UserController@store');`

Comment: so when does the PUT/DELETE etc come in handy then?